# How to translate object in 2D with arrows?

Tags: c++, opengl

I wrote code for rotating a 2D object around the Z axis , also I added some keyboard controls for that rotation like stop , start , and speed up the rotation

what I need now is to Translate the object in 2D with Keyboard arrows .. I need the code for translation in 2D

Comment: This depends entirely the method you're using. If it's 1.x then just use glTranslate.

Answer (score 2):

[This tutorial](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2006.html) provides an excellent overview of how to do object positioning in modern OpenGL. Moving is just doing this positioning in callbacks for key presses.